# Firebase Functions, Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

Tags: javascript, firebase, checkout

I'm building my first firebase function with Js to handle card payments with Checkout.com API, I've installed both checkout and firebase JavaScript SDK's and this is my index.js folder:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { Checkout } = require("checkout-sdk-node");
const cko = new Checkout("sk_test_XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX");

exports.payWithToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        const payment = await cko.payments.request({
            source: {
                token: data.token,
            },
            customer: {
                email: context.auth.token.email
            },
            currency: data.currency,
            amount: data.amount,
        })
        return {
            "Status": payment.status,
            "3DS-Link": payment.redirectLink,
            "Approved": approved,
            "Flagged": risk.flagged,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error.name, error.message, error);
    }
});
```

I think I followed the documentation correctly but for some reason, I couldn't deploy this function to firebase and I get this error:

[Parsing error: Unexpected token =>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFKNn.png)

Comment: check your `package.json`  syntax should be `"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint"
  },`

Answer (score 5):

In **package.json**,

change this

```
    "lint": "eslint .",
```

to this

```
    "lint": "eslint",
```

Comment: This actually just ignores linting.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution on [this page](https://javascript.tutorialink.com/parsing-error-unexpected-token-when-trying-to-deploy-firebase-cloud-function-i-couldnt-find-any-answers-on-here/).

Essentially

> Arrow functions are an ES6 feature, but here you have an async arrow
> function.
>
> Async functions in general are an ES8 (or 2017) feature. Therefore you
> need to specify the following setting at the root of your config:
> parserOptions: {   ecmaVersion: 8 // or 2017 }

So I needed to update my .eslintrc.js file to this

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 8
  },
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'google'],
  rules: {
    'comma-dangle': 'off',
    'quote-props': 'off',
    indent: ['error', 2]
  }
};
```